# Load a crystal report template without CrystalReportViewer in a windows form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

Is there a way to Load a *.rpt file in which binding to the application dataset exists and yet we do not have crystalreportviewer? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You will have to use the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument` object and then set its `FileName` property.

You will find more info on the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225984%28VS.90%29.aspx).